# Change dataframe from stacked to unstacked in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

On the IRIS Dataset, when I convert a series to a dataframe (`X_test.iloc[datapoint]].to_frame()`), this is how its printed out (stacked):

```
sepal length (cm)    5.5
sepal width (cm)     2.6
petal length (cm)    4.4
petal width (cm)     1.2
```

When I convert a list of series points to a dataframe (`df = df.append(result, ignore_index=True)`), this is how its shown (unstacked):

```
   sepal length (cm)  sepal width (cm)  petal length (cm)  petal width (cm)
0                5.5               2.6                5.6               1.8
```

How do I convert the stacked layout to unstacked layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need transpose or use double list for return one row DataFrame:

```
print (X_test)
   sepal length (cm)  sepal width (cm)  petal length (cm)  petal width (cm)
0                5.5               2.6                5.6               1.8
1                4.0               8.0                6.0               8.0
```

---

```
datapoint = 0
df = X_test.iloc[datapoint].to_frame().T
print (df)
   sepal length (cm)  sepal width (cm)  petal length (cm)  petal width (cm)
0                5.5               2.6                5.6               1.8

df = X_test.iloc[[datapoint]]
print (df)
   sepal length (cm)  sepal width (cm)  petal length (cm)  petal width (cm)
0                5.5               2.6                5.6               1.8
```